# Printing WebBrowser control content

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm absolutely new to printing in .NET. I would like to print a page that is displayed in WebBrowser control. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MSDN has an article about this, however their code example demonstrates how use the WebBrowser control to print a Web page without displaying it. :

[How to: Print with a WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3.aspx)

The c# code:

```
private void PrintHelpPage()
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"\\myshare\help.html");
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: how can i use WebBrowser class in asp.net projects?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean themhz? The WebBrowser class is used to display web-pages in a WinForms application. I assume you have a ASP.NET website (WebForms) and you want to print a page? You should use JavaScript for that e.g.: [window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.print)

Comment: I forgot to add example code:
    <a href="#" onClick="window.print();">Print this page!</a>

Comment: @RuudKok any idea if you can set the printer name and settings, instead of just printing with the default printer?

Comment: Could I ask how to print directly to a specific network printer without `printer dialog` or   `save As`