# Handling the final incoming COM events after calling UnregisterTypeForComClients()

Tags: c#, com-interop

*(context: Windows 10 desktop, no UWP)*

For handling Windows Action Center notification activation events I use a `LocalServer32` C# console application, [`STA` and `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198862)*. This works just fine. The executable is started and I get `Activate` calls from COM.

You start getting these calls after calling `RegisterTypeForComClients` and they stop after calling `UnregisterTypeForComClients`. The problem is, even without real concurrency in my case (at least in my direct communication with the object -- I could be wrong as I'm no COM expert) I expect some final `Activate` call(s) might still come in just after I called `UnregisterTypeForComClients`. Missing `Activate` calls is bad and shouldn't happen. I need to handle events for just a bit longer -- but how much longer?

Is there a by-the-book method of making sure I get all the last COM events? Something of a `WaitForComMessageLoopToShutDown` method? I don't want to go with 'a one second wait should be enough'.

**notes**

*`RegisterTypeForComClients` is the equivalent of `CoRegisterClassObject` in COM.*
*`UnregisterTypeForComClients` is the equivalent of `CoDisconnectObject` in COM.*

(*) I know I could use `MTA` with some synchronization, but the question applies there as well. I don't use `MTA` because I'd just be serializing stuff with no real concurrency.

*edit --* **A more elaborate description**

My executable application (an out-of-process server) gets started by OLE automation in Windows because 'things' happen for me to handle. I handle these 'events' (calls to the `Activate` method)

- knowing there could me more than one
- knowing there could be time between them
- using an inactivity timeout of, say, 30 seconds before self terminating
  (for the user within this time span clicking multiple items, or Windows processing delays -- the latter being very small)

Upon expiry of my inactivity timeout I stop the COM object with `UnregisterTypeForComClients`. Now, **crux of my problem**: I ended my loop handling events but a new event from Windows was sent to my server *just* before unregister. Windows says: this event (activation) was sent, I scratch it off my list. *But* - my application hasn't registered it because my handling loop exited already. Event lost! I hope for a solution in the form of:

1. The issue described never occurs, or
2. Something along the lines of *you need to call xyz until it returns x*

As a side note, I started out with the sample (titled 'Sending toast notifications from desktop apps sample' on MSDN) on Github linked to by Hans Passant in the comments. It doesn't address this issue.

Comment: You are asking for a time-machine, can't build those in software.  Typical problem when trying to implement an out-of-process server in C#, you can't get a notification for the final IUnknown::Release() call.  But at least the interface is very simple, you'll have to rely on Windows starting you back up when necessary.  Hopefully without a race.  Use [the code sample](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/tree/master/CS)

Comment: @Hans Passant please see my edit. I assume with *'hopefully without a race'* you refer to what I describe. Thanks!

Comment: You can feel better about it by pinvoking CoAddRefServerObject() when you start up.  When you are ready to shut down, call CoReleaseServerObject().  Which atomically suspends your class factories so when it returns 0 then you can safely allow the process to terminate.  The *additional* requirement is that you can't shut down as long as a client has a reference count on an object but this interface is too simple to make that a serious concern.